# Qualified Col Names Error in bq command line

Tags: google-bigquery

I ran a script via bq command line and got this response (all col. names are fully qualified)

job_134e61cebe274ba4ab73dd6b22a2f38a
Unable to determine schema of SELECT * in this query. Please list column names explicitly.

Exact same request pasted to web UI worked fine.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your query, it appears that the query parser is having trouble computing the column names needed in the query. One suggestion is to take the tables on the right side of the join operations (periods, location, item) and wrap the table name in a subselect with exactly the fields you need -- e.g.
change `LEFT OUTER JOIN item` to `LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT a, b, c FROM item)`.

Let me know if this workaround works for you. I'll file an internal bug to track this.

Comment: That didn't seem to work, see job_d8b671f41e45484eb7a752161702fdec